# Add customer search in openerp version 7 POS frontend view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, odoo

I want to show the openerp partner search pop up on button click in POS. I put the button in `pos.xml` as given below

```
<div id="rightheader">
    <div id="order-selector">
        <button class="neworder-button">+</button>
        <ol id="orders"></ol>
    </div>
    <!-- here goes header buttons -->
    <button class="order-selector-button">Select Customer</button>
</div>
```

I came to know that I need to write a JS code for that but I am not getting how can i call the res_partner search view from JS? 
What I want to achieve is shown in attached image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search this module:
lp:~mmakonnen/openobject-addons/point_of_sale_enhanced-70

It has several enhancements to the POS module like keyboard and the one you're looking for: customer search in POS.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you should follow this tutorial : http://thierry-godin.developpez.com/openerp/tutorial-module-creation-pos-modification-english-version/
Hope this will solve your issue.